# shell script- sed pattern to enclose double quotes around array values ignoring the space delimiter in a component

Tags: shell

I want to enclose all the array values with double quotes ignoring the space delimiter in a component.

for e.g. i'm running the below bash script

```
     bash '''
     #!/bin/bash
     git checkout deltafinal

     metaItems="$(git diff HEAD~1 --name-only)"  #components involved in very last commit in git

     OUTPUT: metaItems=src/profiles/API Only.profile src/profiles/Chatter External User.profile src/profiles/only one.profile

     array=($(echo $metaItems | sed 's! src/!,src/!g'))

     OUTPUT: 
       array= metaItems=src/profiles/API Only.profile,src/profiles/Chatter External User.profile,src/profiles/only one.profile

     Now I want to put the double quotes around every array value starting from "src/" keyword
     ,ending till ".profile" and store them in an array.

    Expected Result:"src/profiles/API Only.profile","src/profiles/Chatter External User.profile","src/profiles/only one.profile"

   P.S. It should ignore all the whitespaces between the characters
```

for e.g. /API and Only and /Chatter External User etc as shown above and treat them as 3 separate components.

```
 src/profiles/API Only.profile- 1 word
 src/profiles/Chatter External User.profile - 2 word
 src/profiles/only one.profile - 3 word
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd think what you'd want would just be

```
array=( $( git diff HEAD~1 --name-only ) )
```

That should insert each item into a distinct element.
Just be super careful with your quoting when accessing elements of the array.
For filenames `a b c` and `d e f`,

```
$: printf "%s\n" ${array[@]} # unquoted, will parse incorrectly
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

is definitly **NOT** the same as

```
$: printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}" # properly quoted, parses properly
a b c
d e f
```

Comment: It's not working.. considering space delimiter as a separate element in the array

For e.g.
array= src/profiles/API Only.profile,src/profiles/Chatter External User.profile,src/profiles/only one.profile

for item in "${array[@]}"

it's considering "src/profiles/API" as one element 
 "Only.profile,src/profiles/Chatter" as 2nd element in next iteration
 "External" and "User.profile" as 3rd and 4th element respectively

how to ignore the space delimiter between the elements and consider them as a one word ?

I think enclosing double quotes around them will work fine.
please suggest.

Comment: This is why I don't put spaces in filenames. :o/